# How can I separate with vertical bar in ellipse shape node in dot file?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to draw a clean network graph like this image.

[image]

But I couldn't find how can I do this. I have to use css for removing part of cell border line, but, as far as I know, dot file is not supported css. I want to insert ellipse shape node, separate node with vertical bar, 
How can I draw a graph that satisfies these conditions? My dot file has self loop, so I can't use networkx. Any other ways are exist? or can I solve use dot file?

My dot file code is

```
digraph  {
    // size = "6,8.5";
    // ratio = "fill";
    // layout = "circo"
    forcelabels = True;
    graph[overlap=False];
    node [shape = ellipse];
    node [fontsize = 10];
    // node [penwidth = 3];
    edge [fontsize = 10];

    // A [pos = "0,2"]
    // B [pos = "-2,-2"]
    // C [pos = "0,1"]
    // D [pos = "2,-2"]
    // E [pos = "0,-3"]

    A
    B
    C
    D
    E;

    node[shape = point];
    x1[style = invis]

    {rank=same; A,C}
    {rank=same; B,E}

    A -> C [label = "4|1.0\l"];

    B -> B [label = "1|:0.979\l"];

    C:nw -> C:ne [label = "3|0.167\l"];
    C -> D [label = "5|0.115\l"];

    D:nw -> C:sw [xlabel = "3|0.103\l4|0:0.315\l"];
    D:se -> x1 [dir = none]
    x1 -> D:sw [xlabel = "5|0.308\l6|0:0.253\l"];

    E -> B [label = "4|0.5\l"];
    E -> D [label = "6|0.5\l"];

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please show what you already have as dot file.

Comment: @albert thank you for your kind that editting question and advice!!

Comment: Note there are some syntax errors in your dot file (at least as far as I can see). The ranks should be like:`     {rank=same; A;C}`
`    {rank=same; B;E`

Comment: When I understand the question correct you want to be able to: 1) draw the vertical line 2) place the label on the left of the vertical line 3) place some other information on the right of the vertical line

Comment: What do you mean with `0.115\l` (edge CD)> did you mean `0.115\\l`?

Comment: @albert uhm.. Ah.. are there syntax errors? I tried compile and it is successful. So I couldn't recognize. And yeah \l is \\l. Thank you for your advice! I'll edit the code follow your advice.  Finally yes your understand is exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to create your nodes, one fairly close (well to my eyes) and pretty easy to replicate.  The other will allow you to recreate your example, but requires using two programs (dot and a program to create individual nodes in svg - like Inkscape)

```
digraph structs {
   // if oblong is good enough, this works
   node [shape=none]
   try3 [label=<
   <TABLE border="1" cellborder="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="rounded" >
     <TR><TD width="40">A</TD><VR/><TD width="40">*111<BR/>*101<BR/>*011</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>];

  // if you really want a circular node, perfectly split
  // create the node images with another program (like Inkscape)
  // and include as an image
  try5 [image="/tmp/split1.svg" label=""]
}
```

producing:
[image]

Comment: Ah.. If I really want to use ellipse or circle shape, I have to import image file... Thank you very much!!